# extract number of bytes out of a file

Tags: command-line, dd

Is it possible to extract a few number of bytes out of a file using dd ? The file is located on a secondary drive.

I apologize if this is a simple question however I'm no pro at command line.

Answer (score 9):

If this is `file`:

```
hello world how are you today
```

Then this would extract `world` from `file`:

```
 dd bs=1 skip=6 count=5 if=file
```

It skips 6 bytes (`hello_`), reads 5 bytes (`world`), and ignores the rest.

So with `skip`, `count`, and `bs=1` (or alternatively, when using GNU dd, using the count_bytes/skip_bytes flag), you can extract specific byte ranges at byte resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. What about the 'if' and 'of' ?  
That is mainly my problem.  
  
I've tried dd if=/dev/sdb2/..../'directoryname' of=/dev/sdb2/..../'directoryname 2' bs=13172736b

The below should extract a number of bytes out of a Virtual Machine's virtual hdd (.vmdk file), which resides in a folder called 'Windows 7 vmware'  

Actual text is dd if=/dev/sdb2/media/Used\ for\ VMs/ of=/media/Used\ for\ VMs/Windows\ 7\ vmware bs=13172736b

Comment: There is no `/dev/sdb2/pathname`... you can either write raw data to the device, or you have to use `mount` so it's `/mnt/sdb2/pathname`. This sounds like an X Y problem so maybe you should have asked your real question...